# composer - install new package without updating other packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I added a package in the `require` block of my `composer.json`.

I do a `composer install` and it says `Nothing to install or update.`

In my understanding, `composer update` would work but I shouldn't do that because it updates the versions of the other packages to the latest, but I haven't tested my code on them.

How do I install that new package?

Answer (score 8):

**The Command Line.**

You don't have to add the new packages manually to your `composer.json` file and then do a `composer install or update`. **Use The Command Line**

Installing new packages from the command line automatically adds it to your `composer.json` file and it does not update previously installed packages.

From the project root, simply run:

```
composer require package/name
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I did this but it only added the package to the `require` block, it did not install. When I do `composer install`, is says, `Nothing to install or update.`

Comment: @talk2toyin has right. If you use the **command line**, as suggested, composer installs only the new package and updates both `composer.json` and `composer.lock`.

Comment: For me running require on one package is still causing everything to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

Using composer require will also update other dependencies.
We can install a new package without updating anything else like this:

```
composer require package/name --no-update
```

this will add your package to composer.json, leaving composer.lock intact.

```
composer update package/name
```

this will now install/update your new package, adding it to composer.lock. This will not update any other dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, if you have already added package(s) to your `require` block in `composer.json`, it's as simple as listing them all after the `update` command to exclude existing packages from being updated. First, simulate update to ensure you're happy with the result:

```sh
composer update --dry-run vendor/project vendor2/project2
```

If okay, run it again with the `--dry-run` argument removed.

You can see the output of updating new/specific packages is different from that of:

```sh
composer update --dry-run
```

Your `composer.lock` file should be on version control or otherwise backed up so you can restore it & revert all packages in the event of failure.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks. I added a package to my `composer.json` which was actually a fork of another package, that I had to specify in `repositories`, as shown [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs). For some reason, `composer install` would not pick up the package, but running `composer update vendor/other-package` worked.